# Pooling Layer doesn't support after zero_mask = True in embedding layer (Keras)

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, masking, named-entity-recognition, crf

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[0], output_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[1], input_length=n_in, weights=[wordEmbeddings], trainable=False, **zero_mask=True**))       
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.5, dropout=0.5, name='bilstm1')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation="relu")))
model.summary()
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=7, strides=1))
crf = CRF(n_out)
model.add(crf)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=crf_loss, metrics=[crf_viterbi_accuracy])
```

Model Summary

[image]

This model works fine. But I am getting negative values for loss function.

[image]

So I changed the attribute zero_mask=True in embedding layer and tried to train the model. But then I got an error as below.

"MaxPooling1D is not supported with masking."

Any help with this really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a `GlobalMaxPooling1D`? Since you're not really pooling with a size 7 for length 7....

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives for the pooling layer:

- `GlobalMaxPooling1D()` + `Reshape((1, 100))`
- `Lambda(lambda x: K.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))`

If your loss is strange, a double check in the ranges of your data may be a good idea.